# C++ ignore \x inside string, how to make it plain text?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, escaping, stdstring

i have a problem with \x inside a string.
how can i make that sprintf_s just accept the  single \x (taking it as plain text?, compiler doesnt accept only "\x") with the following code my const char* have a double backslash inside...

```
sprintf_s(buf, "\\x%02X")
```

; -> output is \\0xA0, should be only \xA0

thanks

Comment: If this is truly what you get as the result, then this must be a bug in your C++ compiler.

Comment: There is no `sprintf_s` in standard C++. It's either a C function or MSVC++. The C version expects at least 3 parameters so I think it's MSVC++. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sprintf-s-sprintf-s-l-swprintf-s-swprintf-s-l?view=msvc-160

Comment: i cant just put "\x" as normal characters inside the string.. thats the problem. even not with string.append("\\x"), it will result in 2 backslashes..;

Comment: (http://prntscr.com/vqqs1d) thats how its looking inside the debugger inside visual studio..

Comment: You must be peaking at the value with the debugger. If you where to output the data to a file, you would see `\x7A` as the value, not `\\x7A`. The debugger is showing you that you have escaped the backslash.

Comment: In fact, drag your buf to the memory window and you will see it is really a single backslash

Comment: @lakeweb the compiler shows this: [link](prntscr.com/vqqs1d) problem is i need to write it over memcpy to a memory address.. and with double backslash all crashes. when i write that string manually, it works ( single backslash )

Comment: Hi Steven, this is something else. I don't typically use `sprintf_s` so I tested with what you posted. It works fine for me. Update your question with the error message, a linker error? Apparently you had it compiling and running at one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio debugger on displays the backslashes so there is no ambiguity about what you have escaped. If you copy the value you will have it quoted. If you insert a quote, it will be backslashed in the debugger display.

```
"\\x7B\""
```

The two outer quotes are to show the containment of the value. That would show in a memory window as

```
\x7B"
```

And yes, it is an error to `\x` in a quoted string.

Here are the legal [escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).